# How to access role name in UserViewModel with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, automapper

How to access role name in UserViewModel with AutoMapper ?

my user model :

```
 public class User : IdentityUser<long, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
    {

    }
```

my role model :

```
 public class Role : IdentityRole<long, UserRole>
    {

    }
```

my userRole model :

```
 public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
    {
    }
```

my userViewModel :

```
 public class UserViewModel
    {
        public List<string> RoleNames { get; set; }
    }
```

my mapping :

```
    CreateMap<List<UserRole>, List<string>>().ConvertUsing(new UserRoleConverter());

    CreateMap<User, >()
        .ForMember(d => d.RoleNames, m => m.MapFrom(s =>  s.Roles));
```

my userRole Converter :

```
 public class UserRoleConverter : ITypeConverter<List<UserRole>, List<string>>
    {
        public List<string> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var userRole = context.SourceValue;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the missing class in `CreateMap<User, >()`?

Comment: CreateMap<User,UserViewModel>()

Answer (score 0):

Your example is incomplete - your User mapping references a `Roles` property which does not exist in the example. So it isn't clear if this is a list of `Role` or `UserRole` objects.

However, making a few assumptions, this can be made to work.

Firstly, your TypeConverter should convert between `UserRole` and `string`, **not** between lists:

```
public class UserRoleConverter : ITypeConverter<UserRole, string>
{
    public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
         // Assuming a "Name" property on UserRole
         return ((UserRole)context.SourceValue).Name;
    }
}
```

So the mapping should look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserRole, string>().ConvertUsing(new UserRoleConverter());
```

Then this test should pass:

```
User user = new User
{
    Roles = new List<UserRole>
    {
      // Assume a constructor to set the Name
      new UserRole("Role1"),
      new UserRole("Role2")
    }
};

UserViewModel uvm = Mapper.Map<User, UserViewModel>(user);

Assert.AreEqual(2, uvm.RoleNames.Count);
Assert.AreEqual("Role1", uvm.RoleNames.First());
Assert.AreEqual("Role2", uvm.RoleNames.Last());
```